# Schema.org LocalBusiness openingHours and bank holidays/public holidays

Tags: date, schema.org

I would like to know how to deal with bank holidays (in the UK) and christmas holidays when using [Schema.org's `openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours).

There are a few dates in the UK where a lot of businesses close, so these dates need to be excluded, they will also change slightly every year: https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`openingHours`](http://schema.org/openingHours) property doesn’t allow excluding specific dates.

With [`specialOpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/specialOpeningHoursSpecification) you can override the general opening hours that were specified with `openingHours` or [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification) (which is a more expressive alternative to `openingHours`).

The properties `specialOpeningHoursSpecification` and `openingHoursSpecification` take [`OpeningHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) as value.

In `OpeningHoursSpecification`, you can use the [`dayOfWeek`](http://schema.org/dayOfWeek) property to specify the day it’s about. It expects a [`DayOfWeek`](http://schema.org/DayOfWeek) value (which is an enumeration). It contains a value for each day in the week ([`Monday`](http://schema.org/Monday), [`Tuesday`](http://schema.org/Tuesday), etc.), but also the "special" value [`PublicHolidays`](http://schema.org/PublicHolidays):

> This stands for any day that is a public holiday; it is a placeholder for all official public holidays in some particular location.

So if you want to state that you are closed on (your location’s) public holidays, you could use something like this:

```html
<div itemprop="specialOpeningHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification">
  <link itemprop="dayOfWeek" href="http://schema.org/PublicHolidays" />
  <p itemprop="description">‎Closed on public holidays.</p>
</div>
```

(It conveys that it’s closed because the `opens` property is not provided.)

Comment: Thanks for input, it's a shame that you have to do logic for dates manually, but at least it's possible. Found a good example of how to mark this up on: [OpeningHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)  turns out there are 2 versions as well [OpeningHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification)  and [openingHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification). That could be improved hah!

Comment: @user1463467: **A)** What would be the alternative to doing "logic for dates manually"? (honest question) -- **B)** About the 2 versions: `OpeningHoursSpecification` is a type, `openingHoursSpecification` is a property. In Microdata it would be for example: `itemprop="openingHoursSpecification" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification"` (i.e., the case matters). Or do you mean something different?

Comment: **A**: There could eventually be a boolean for national holidays dependent on locale [discussed here](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1139).

**B**: Yes that's what I meant, I was just pointing that out incase it caught someone out. "Example 2" on [OpeningHoursSpecification](http://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification) appears to be a good way to mark that up if you did want to do it.

Comment: @user1463467: Ah, good find. I didn’t notice that `PublicHolidays` was added. I edited my answer and included an example.

Comment: Nice one, though json+ld for the win :D

Answer (score 0):

Actually, already the established http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification DOES allow excluding specific dates via the validFrom and validThrough properties of the OpeningHoursSpecification attached thereto.

See http://ebusiness-unibw.org/pipermail/goodrelations/2010-October/000261.html for an example. Note that the example is in the context of the original GoodRelations vocabulary (now integrated into schema.org), so there are some naming differences, described here:

http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/Cookbook/Schema.org#Naming_Differences